# Secure Chat Application + GUI

Tags: java, python, c, chat

I have been given a semester project in Network Security. The project is to implement a "secure" internet messaging system.

There will be a client and a server whose purpose is to register users, provide list of online users and initiate communication between users. We can write our own protocol which is not of concern for this question (I need help with the programing language)

Here are a few things:

1. We have to use cryptographic libraries for secure communication
2. We can only use languages like Python, Java, C, C++
3. It would be nice to have a graphical interface

So, I would like to know which would be the best programing language for this?
I thought of using C with ncurses. Do you think java or python is better? If so, i need some pointers on GUI interfacing.

Comment: What does "primitive languages" mean?  There's a few worlds of difference between Python and C.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean primitive. That was a mistake

Comment: I guess I'm still confused by the list of languages; what would be an example of a language you _can't_ use?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using python with [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/). Check this [link](http://popdevelop.com/2010/04/how-to-build-an-executable-application-from-your-python-script-qt-special/), it can help you get started with the GUI part.